# python for col in col if - exclude specific string

Tags: python, for-loop, string-matching

I am trying to split some dataframes up, and there are a number of them to be split/created so i am trying to use a for loop, but can't quite get it to do what i want.

there is a dataframe (i've called it column_names below) that only contains column names that are in common between a number of these smaller dataframes that i want it to look at to exclude 2 specific columns.

i am using the following:

```
# target and features
target = ['rougher.output.recovery', 'final.output.recovery']
features = [col for col in column_names if ~col.str.contains('recovery')]
```

with the goal of feeding those into dataframes like this:

```
#dataframes for each step train and test targets
target_train, target_test = train_imp[target].values,test_imp[target].values
features_train, features_test = train_imp[features].values,test_imp[features].values
```

i'm trying to exclude columns that contain `recovery` in their name, but i'm not quite getting it right.

i've tried:

```
[col for col in train_test if col != ['rougher.output.recovery', 'final.output.recovery']
```

and

```
[col for col in train_test if not 'rougher.output.recovery' or 'final.output.recovery']
```

but they don't actually exclude the columns i want to exclude?

i've also tried the above .contains which doesn't work, i am frankly pretty new to python and am not sure what else to try?

thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also can't comment (not enough reputation, just registered a few days ago), sorry for posting another answer. Use the following comprehension:

```
features = [col for col in column_names if 'recovery' not in col]
```

Both of your tries can be corrected too:

```
[col for col in train_test if col not in ['rougher.output.recovery', 'final.output.recovery']

[col for col in train_test if col != 'rougher.output.recovery' and col != 'final.output.recovery']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `features = [col for col in column_names if 'recovery' not in col.contains('recovery')]`

Comment: i get the error "str object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: Sorry, spellcheck truncated my answer... Edited now